# Problem using the "mask slice to new object" tool

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

I'm using Blender 3.1.2. I'm trying to separate the hands from the rest of the body:

[image]

But when I press "mask slice to new object", this happens:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix this? Thank you :)

edit: I tried masking just one hand instead of both, the same thing happens

Comment: Ran into this exact issue when attempting to complete the Thor course from Udemy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the scale of your object in Object mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you! My first time learning of the apply feature :)